# avr-gcc: How to use __attribute__((address)) with EEMEM?

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, avr-gcc

Are these attributes incompatible?  The address attribute seems to be ignored, emitting no warnings (-Wall).

(For reference, EEMEM is defined in **eeprom.h** as: `#define EEMEM __attribute__((section(".eeprom")))`.)

Using a declaration like:

`uint8_t storedFlags EEMEM __attribute__((address (100)));`

(and similarly for all the others) results in the variables being placed in whatever order the linker prefers, ignoring my attribute.  Order of attributes doesn't make a difference.

I am aware of the preferred method (creating sections and passing their locations to the linker).  I was just looking to shove them around for the moment, as I'm in active development and adding and removing allocations in EEPROM; I'd rather things not move around every other build so I don't have to reprogram EEPROM from default values every damn time.  Worst of all, I'm sure I've done precisely this before, and had it work.  Version differences?  Coincidental assignments?  (I have GCC 3.4 and 8.1, not sure what that project used; I'm using 8.1 for this one.)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Variable-Attributes.html) for the *address* attribute states:</strike>

> Variables with the address attribute are used to address memory-mapped peripherals that may lie outside the io address range.

Looking at the [AVR memory space](https://microchipdeveloper.com/8avr:memory) shows the I/O addresses fall under the SRAM data memory space.

This explains why your construct doesn't work as expected since EEMEM and the *address* attribute map to conflicting memory sections.

Edit:  Testing with avr-gcc 3.6.2 suggest that the section attribute overrides the address attribute (without warning). Using eeprom_read_byte to read data from EEPROM, the following example gets correctly compiled by avr-gcc (correct because the address 0x0123 is passed to the eeprom_read_byte function):

```
#include <avr/eeprom.h>

uint8_t __attribute__((address (0x0123))) storedFlags;
int main(void){
  if (eeprom_read_byte(&storedFlags) == 1){
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Edit2: tested on avr-gcc 11.1, also generates correct instructions.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what they mean; the IO space is in SRAM, distinguished only by the ability to access it with certain fast instructions (IN, OUT, etc.). Essentially all peripherals lie outside that range already. And the official headers just access those with raw (literal) pointers. Also, if it depends on section, shouldn't it say which section it requires (e.g. .data)? Is this just a redundant attribute then? Or badly documented?

Comment: Some testing with avr-gcc 3.6.2 reveals that the section attribute appears to override the address.  Thus specifying a section attribute will wipe the address attribute and the linker will place the variable starting at address 0 in the EEPROM space.  It seems that using only the address attribute leads to the correct apparent location.  Since one needs to use the eeprom_* functions to access EEPROM addresses it is not necessary to specify the .eeprom section AFAICS. I will add an example .

Comment: Interesting: using it in .data anyway, which _would_ be stupid because other stuff is linked there, except, that's all peripheral space anyway (0 to 0xfff or thereabouts on most chips, whereas EEPROM is smaller), so there won't actually be any conflict.  Downside: can't initialize .eeprom, that still needs to be linked somehow. So the original problem remains for that use case, hmm.